# How to find the x-axis and y-axis index of a value in 2-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indices

StackOverflow! I have hit a wall regarding finding the indices of a 2-dimensional array. I am trying to find the least value in the array and returns the corresponding (x,y) indices.

I have tried using `np.argmin(a,axis=0)` and `np.argmin(a,axis=1)` simultaneously to find the x and y indices respectively.

```py
import numpy as np
a =  ([[3.2,  0,  0.5, 5.8], 
       [   6,  1,  6.2, 7.1],
       [ 3.8,  5,  2.7, 3.7]])
def axis(a):
    x_min = np.argmin(a,axis = 0)
    y_min = np.argmax(a,axis = 1)

    return x_min,y_min

a1,a2=axis(a)

print('x is ',a1)
print('y is ',a2)
```

The output should be: `x is 0` and `y is 1` as zero is the least value in the array.
However, the actual output is a list of integers.

Comment: Shouldn't it return indices `(0,0)` as `-3.2` is the least value?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argmin` without axis is the location in a flattened version of `a`:

```
In [200]: a =np.array([[-3.2,  0,  0.5, 5.8],  
     ...:        [   6,  1,  6.2, 7.1], 
     ...:        [ 3.8,  5,  2.7, 3.7]])                                                                     
In [201]: np.argmin(a, axis=0)                                                                               
Out[201]: array([0, 0, 0, 2])   # smallest in each of the 4 columns
In [202]: np.argmin(a, axis=1)                                                                               
Out[202]: array([0, 1, 2])      # smallest in each of the 3 rows
```

`unravel` can convert that to the 2d indices:

```
In [203]: np.argmin(a)                                                                                       
Out[203]: 0
In [204]: np.unravel_index(np.argmin(a), a.shape)                                                            
Out[204]: (0, 0)
In [205]: np.unravel_index(1, a.shape)                                                                       
Out[205]: (0, 1)
```

This use is documented in `argmin`:

```
Indices of the minimum elements of a N-dimensional array:

>>> ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(a, axis=None), a.shape)
>>> ind
(0, 0)
>>> a[ind]
10
```

Answer (score -1):

To get indices of the minimum/maximum value

```py
import numpy as np
a =([[-3.2,  0,  0.5, 5.8], 
       [   6,  1,  6.2, 7.1],
       [ 3.8,  5,  2.7, 3.7]])
xyMin = np.argwhere(a == np.min(a)) #Indices of Minimum
xyMax = np.argwhere(a == np.max(a)) #Indices of Maximum

xIndex = xyMin[0][0] #x-index
yIndex = xyMin[0][1] #y-index
```

Or you can use the .flatten() to convert 2D array into one dimension as below

```py
xyMin = np.argwhere(a == np.min(a)).flatten() #Indices of Minimum
xIndex = xyMin[0] #x-index
```

Comment: How do you separate them to get, for example, x is 1 and y is 0 instead of (0,1)?

Comment: @0verl0rd21 edited the code to access the individual index.